# How can i do paypal payment direct transfer to merchant account

Tags: paypal, transfer, bank

How can i do **recurring payment with credit card in paypal**. Payment should directly transfer to merchant bank account.

Can anyone give solution for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For that you can refer this link.

[Paypal direct payment to merchant](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-pro/integration-guide/direct-payment/)